# How can I get cookie in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

The title of my question seems duplicate, but it isn't. I've tested all existing approaches in the internet.

Here is my code:

```
dd($request->cookie('guarantee_ticket'));
// I also have tested this: dd(Cookie::get('guarantee_ticket'));
```

And the result is `null`, while that cookie is exists in the browser. I can see it:

[image]

Any idea how can I get the value of that cookie?

Comment: Is this cookie created by laravel ?

Comment: @RezaSh Yes, `setcookie('guarantee_ticket', json_encode([$request->problem_title, $request->problem_description, $doesnot_turn_on]), time()+86400);`

Comment: as I remember laravel just handle cookies create its own api, try to set the cookie by laravel helpers functons or simply use $_COOKIE['guarantee_ticket']

Comment: @RezaSh Yes this works `$_COOKIE['guarantee_ticket'] `. But I like to do that with laravel functions .. any idea?

Comment: have you passed the web middleware ?

Comment: @RezaSh Yes ...

Comment: Laravel  requires encrypted cookies, and doesn't parse default php cookies, IF you need to use global cookies you may disable this encryption by removing 
'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
from Http\Controllers\Kernel
If this worked for you please let me know to provide a complete answer from these comments

Comment: Is the cookie being sent with the request?

Answer (score 2):

Here, I'm mention set and get a cookie in laravel simple example following.

First of the create a controller.

1.**php artisan make:controller CookieController**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CookieController extends Controller {

  **/* below code a set a cookie in browser */**
   public function setCookie(Request $request){
      $response = new Response('Hello World');
      $response->withCookie(cookie('name', 'Anything else'));
      return $response;
   }
  **/* below code a get a cookie in browser */**
   public function getCookie(Request $request){
      $value = $request->cookie('name');
      echo $value;
   }
}
```

1. **Add a follwing line code in routes/web.php file** (Laravel 5.4)

```
Route::get('/cookie/set','CookieController@setCookie');

Route::get('/cookie/get','CookieController@getCookie');
```

And all files add-in project than a run program easily gets a cookie.